# Unable to display the video on the webpage which is initially paused using an iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, dom-manipulation

I need help with a small web development issue
I am unable to display the video on the webpage which is initially paused using an iframe tag

Code:

```
<iframe src="../videos/java/java7.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

I know that I can use youtube API to embed videos and they will be initially paused but is there any way to embed my own videos (that are not available anywhere online like yt or anywhere else) which are linked using iframe tag to be initially paused when page is loaded using HTML, CSS or JS?

Comment: i saw many VanillaJs and jQuery codes for this issue online but none of them seem to work for me :(

Comment: New policy in browsers?

Comment: not that i know about.

Comment: I tried simulating a click on all iframes to pause them when the window loads but i failed in that also. Now I am searching for a code to press Ctrl+M keys using javascript so that they play in muted mode atleast

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this best way is to use 2 pages. On the first page make a video player. Suppose we are giving the page name `videoPlayer.html`

Here is the code of the `videoPlayer.html` page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Video Player</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 100%!important;
      height: 100%!important;
    }
    video {
      width: 100%!important;
      height: 100%!important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video controls>
    <source src="../videos/java/java7.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Now finally open a page that you want and embed the videoPlayer.html page. Suppose we are naming it as `index.html`

Here is the code of `index.html` page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Main page to embed iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="path/to/videoPlayer.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, this is a good but a very lengthy solution. Is there any way to simulate a click at the pause button or center of an iframe using javascript? If I can just click iframe tags when document is loaded, it would be much easier.

Comment: loading raw .mp4 file directly using iframe will not allow you to control the video element. If you want to use an iframe to class a .mp4 it is the best option. If you take a look on Vimeo or youtube you can see their iframe link is not a .mp4 file is an HTML page. Here a .mp4 is called via `<video>` element. But if you want to just call a .mp4 file instead of using an iframe just use the `<video>` element. You can take look at the `videoPlayer.html` page.